# Step Function - automatic retry from any lambda functions?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have many Lambda functions in the Step Function state, is there a way to automatically do a retry (max three times) if any lambda functions throw an error of `Lambda.TooManyRequestsException`

Basically, the Lambda function is throttled.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the "Retry" field to your task. This allows a task (e.g. a lambda function) in the state machine structure to be retried on specified errors.

Example:

```
"execute_lambda": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
  "Parameters": {
    "FunctionName": "someFunction",
  },
  "Retry": [
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [
        "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
      ],
      "IntervalSeconds": 5,
      "MaxAttempts": 3,
      "BackoffRate": 1.5
    }
  ],
  "Next": "next_job"
},
```

More information and examples can be found: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#error-handling-retrying-after-an-error